# Error: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: linux, bash, 64-bit, raspberry-pi

By setting up a Musicbot for TeamSpeak on my rasperrypi an error occurred while trying to launch it.

```
musikbot@raspberrypi:/opt/ts3soundboard $ ./ts3bot -update
-bash: ./ts3bot: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I already searched for the error but nothing helped me out.
and no it's not caused by the 64bit architecture.

file ts3bot gives me the following information:

```
ts3bot: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=d24379e638b6028d2ce4eeda954b9273c18c4acd, not stripped
```

I hope someone can help me!
(sorry for my bad english ^^)

Comment: please see this https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=8353

Answer (score 3):

Look at that output from `file`:

```
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64...
```

The Raspberry Pi is not an x86_64 (Intel) platform.  You need to install binaries appropriate for the Pi.

Comment: okay but which binary should i install?

Comment: @psychonaut RasPis are ARM based.  You either need an ARM binary, or compile from source.

Comment: The 'correct' architecture for a rpi should be arm-hf I believe